# How do I configure the DNS in my GoDaddy account to point it to my AWS server

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns

I have a ubuntu server running on ec2 . I have hosted a wp site on /var/www/html/wp . I have a domain at godaddy . I need to connect the domain name to the ubuntu server that's running wp.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, let's say you have a domain called example.com and you want the wordpress site to be at www.example.com. And your IP address @ ec2 is x.x.x.x

I recommend you create and use an Elastic IP so your IP address doesn't keep changing every time you restart your server.

Go to GoDaddy-> Your Domain -> Manage DNS.

In the Manage DNS section, you can do one of two things.

A. If you want www.example.com to point to your server.

Create a new Host Record (or A Record)
Link www to x.x.x.x (create an A record with Host -> www, Points to -> x.x.x.x)

B. If you want example.com and www.example.com to point to x.x.x.x
1. Create an Host (A) record (which links your domain to your IP). 
Link @ (which is short hand for your domain name, ie. example.com) to x.x.x.x

2. Now create a cname alias that links www to the above A record.
   Host -> www, Points to -> @ (note that I used the @ shorthand for the A record).